# Compiling VLC source code on windows visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, open-source, vlc

VLC is open source project. I want to edit the source of it. i want to do some changes in the interface like changing title window, icon etc. But I am very confused how to do this. I downloaded the source it contained headers file, cpp files, makefile etc. now I am stuck what to do next.\

can i open the source in visual studio like a windows form application and do the drag drop, changing etc.

how to do this.

or how to edit the code and compile it make source. i am using windows 7. i dont have knowledge of install makeinstall.

so i need a step by step walkthrough.

Comment: With no disrespect intended, if you're not sure how to compile the code, you probably won't get very far in making useful edits to the code.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth but if someone guide me i will be able to do that, if it was a visual studio solution it would be easier for me, but it uses make, make install. i am not familiar with them,

Answer (score 0):

Compiling on Visual Studio will never be possible due to the nature of Visual Studio. Instead, you need MinGW and Msys to compile natively on Windows 7: http://wiki.videolan.org/Win32Compile

Comment: Then how come this user does it regularly: http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=107425 ?

Comment: Never say never, each release of VS adds more support for standards based native code.